# How to add an item to an array in controller with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

To add an item to an array, call `push()`, like this.
`myArgument.myArray.push(this.myObject)`

I tried with this but not getting any answer? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Put some code, context and error trace please

Comment: Yep, what is the error?

Comment: Guess: myArgument.myArray is not defined as an array, so .push() fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this:

```
var tempList =[];
var itemInfo = new Object;
tempList.push(itemInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your array first. i.e before inserting items into it. In your controller

```
$scope.myArray = [];
$scope.myArray.push(object);
```

Comment: Better not to provide the solution with `$scope` in it. Might be misleading.

Comment: @zcui93 Its recommended to use $scope for storing variables.

Comment: Any source for the recommendation? For the question asked, I would rather to answer `this.myArray`

Comment: `$scope` inheritance may be one of the reason it's not recommended. And `$scope` is not directly related to the question, as no explanation on why using `$scope` not simply declare a `var`.

Comment: @zcui93 **$scope inheritance** doesn't make it non-recommended. Why don't you write your own answer for your coding standards.

Comment: I won't comment more. The reason is clear, `$scope` is not asked at all, array is asked instead.